# Add meta tag to search results

Tags: search, user-meta

In the search results I use author_name=something in the url to restrict the results. The Problem is that domain.com/?s=searchterm and domain.com/?s=searchterm&author_name=something have the same meta tags. How can I add the author_name value to the meta tags?

Comment: Which meta tags? There are so many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am asuming you want to amend the `<title>` tag?

Add this in functions.php

```
  add_filter('wp_title', 'my_custom_page_title');

  function my_custom_page_title($title) { 
    global $s;
    if( isset($_REQUEST['author_name']) && is_search() ) {
            $title = 'Search Results for '.$s.' from author '.$_REQUEST['author_name'];
    }
    return $title;  
  }
```

If `$s` returns blank replace that with `$_REQUEST['s']`

Comment: Is it possible to get the user display_name as meta tag instead the request?

Comment: Your author_name input param would have to be the author ID, then you would call get_userdata(AUTHOR_ID); and return as $author_data->display_name; in your custom page title function.